# How to find a maximum value from a list of json pairs from a json string using Excel vba?

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am totally new in VBA and coding.
Suppose i have a json string like this:

```
jsonstr = [{"id":"BGFV:US","dateTimeRanges":{},"price":[{"date":"2019-08-07","value":2.03},{"date":"2019-08-08","value":1.98},{"date":"2019-08-09","value":1.98},{"date":"2019-08-12","value":1.9100000000000001},{"date":"2019-08-13","value":1.9100000000000001},{"date":"2019-08-14","value":1.8},{"date":"2019-08-15","value":1.7},{"date":"2019-08-16","value":1.77},{"date":"2019-08-19","value":1.8399999999999999},{"date":"2019-08-20","value":1.8199999999999998},{"date":"2019-08-21","value":1.9100000000000001},{"date":"2019-08-22","value":1.97},{"date":"2019-08-23","value":1.95},{"date":"2019-08-26","value":1.96},{"date":"2019-08-27","value":2.07},{"date":"2019-08-28","value":1.87},{"date":"2019-08-29","value":1.87},{"date":"2019-08-30","value":1.79},{"date":"2019-09-03","value":1.7},{"date":"2019-09-04","value":1.71},{"date":"2019-09-05","value":1.79},{"date":"2019-09-06","value":1.8599999999999999}],"timeZoneOffset":-4,"nyTradeStartTime":"09:30:00.000","nyTradeEndTime":"16:30:00.000","priceMinDecimals":2,"lastUpdateDate":"2019-09-06","lastPrice":1.86}]
```

I am trying to get data means " highest value" of the stock price from the above json string.

However, I only want the highest value of the “value” variable displayed in row 2 in my excel sheet.

I have written the following macro:
Please see above the part of code section.

```
Sub getData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Double

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    'Last row find
    lastrow = ws.Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

    'Clear Prior Prices
    ws.Range("B2:B" & lastrow).ClearContents

    n = 2

    'Get Symbols list
    For Each Symbol In rng

        Dim httpObject As Object

        Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        Dim sURL As String

        sURL = "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & Symbol & "%3AUS?timeFrame=1_MONTH"

        Dim sRequest As String

        sRequest = sURL

        httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False

        httpObject.send

        Dim sGetResult As String

        sGetResult = httpObject.responseText

        Dim oJSON As Variant

        Set oJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)

        On Error Resume Next

        For Each item In oJSON(price)

            ws.Cells(n, 2).Value = item("value")

        Next item

        n = n + 1
    Next Symbol

    MsgBox ("Data is downloaded.")
End Sub
```

When I run this code, it gives no error and no output.
I think I am missing some basic things but still I am unable to find it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a function which loops all prices and does the comparison; returning the highest found value. Rather than loop the range itself, I would transfer the values to an array and loop that as it is faster. Get rid of the hungarian notation for your variables. Also, create the `http` variable once outside loop.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, symbols()
    Dim lastRow As Long, n As Long, http As Object

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).ClearContents
    symbols = Application.Transpose(rng.Value) 'rng.Value creates 2D array. Transpose converts to 1D.

    Dim response As String, json As Object

    For n = LBound(symbols) To UBound(symbols)
        With http
            .Open "GET", "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & symbols(n) & "%3AUS?timeFrame=1_MONTH", False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'mitigate for caching between runs
            .send
            response = .responseText
        End With
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
        ws.Cells(n + 1, 3).Value = GetMaxPrice(json)
        Set json = Nothing
    Next

    MsgBox "Data is downloaded."
End Sub

Public Function GetMaxPrice(ByVal json As Object) As Variant
    Dim prices As Object, price As Object, maxPrice As Double
    On Error GoTo errhand
    Set prices = json(1)("price")
    For Each price In prices
        If price("value") > maxPrice Then maxPrice = price("value")
    Next
    GetMaxPrice = maxPrice
    Exit Function
errhand:
    GetMaxPrice = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

---

**Reading (so as to tailor error handling to your requirements):**

1. [Error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement)
2. [CVErr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function)

---

Edit:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, symbols()
    Dim lastRow As Long, n As Long, http As Object

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).ClearContents
    symbols = Application.Transpose(rng.Value) 'rng.Value creates 2D array. Transpose converts to 1D.

    Dim response As String, json As Object, arr()

    For n = LBound(symbols) To UBound(symbols)
        DoEvents
        With http
            .Open "GET", "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/api/bulk-time-series/price/" & symbols(n) & "%3AUS?timeFrame=1_MONTH", False
            .setrequestheader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT" 'mitigate for caching between runs
            .setrequestheader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
            .send
            response = .responseText
        End With
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(response)
        arr = GetPrices(json)
        ws.Cells(n + 1, 2).Value = arr(0)
        ws.Cells(n + 1, 3).Value = arr(1)
        ws.Cells(n + 1, 4).Value = arr(2)
        Set json = Nothing
    Next

    MsgBox "Data is downloaded."
End Sub

Public Function GetPrices(ByVal json As Object) As Variant
    Dim prices As Object, price As Object, maxPrice As Double, minPrice As Double, lastPrice As Double
    On Error GoTo errhand
    Set prices = json(1)("price")
    minPrice = prices(1)("value"): maxPrice = minPrice
    For Each price In prices
        If price("value") > maxPrice Then maxPrice = price("value")
        If price("value") < minPrice Then minPrice = price("value")
    Next
    lastPrice = json(1)("lastPrice")
    GetPrices = Array(lastPrice, maxPrice, minPrice)
    Exit Function
errhand:
    GetPrices = Array(CVErr(xlErrNA), CVErr(xlErrNA), CVErr(xlErrNA))
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, your code works. But It showing error that is,     Run-time Error  '10001':    Error parsing JSON:  Bad request ^    Expecting '{' or '[' .                                                                     Actually I have 60 symbol, But it showing output of only 30 symbol and after that showing Run-time error.

Comment: Suppose, I want the highest value of the “value” variable displayed in row 2 and in column 3 in my excel sheet. Then, how I will display that?

Comment: Hi Rasmita! So question 1) You can share your 60 symbols via https://pastebin.com/ and I will have a look. It seems you have an error that needs handling and for that you have the links I included in the _Reading_ section of answer. 2) I don't understand r2c3 if you have 60 values you are retrieving then you cannot be writing them all to a single cell. Please can you clarify. Say first symbol is in A2 where will highest price go? Then for next symbol in A3 where will price go? ......

Comment: Actually, the highest price of the first symbol is in A2 will go  C2, and value of second symbol is in A3 will go C3, A4 will go C4............A60 will go C60 like this

Comment: Code updated to write to Column C as per your comment. Please let me know if this is as expected.

Comment: Yes, But after updated still it showing highest price in column B. And it showing other data in column C. I have share my excel sheet via  pastebin.com and you can see that now.

Comment: Actually, my requirement is that , I want the Last-Price value in Column "B", highest price value in Column "C" and Lowest price value in Column "D"  of the symbols respectively. Please help on this.-Thank You

Comment: You should state all the requirements up front when you first ask the question rather than keep making changes. It saves us both a lot of time. I will have a look. Where is the pastebin link please?

Comment: My paste name is RasmitaExcelSheet. Just check it in pastebin.com. I just sent it.

Comment: Can't see it. Can you drop the actual link here please.

Comment: I also updated my code just before few minutes.Please have a look on this.-Thank You

Comment: Thanks. Assuming that is supposed to represent your sheet does this not mean you already have results in columns B and C and D? Please don't edit your question to include my code. Just update for the data items you need to see in response.

Comment: I have added a version to get all items but note that you will get blocked pretty quickly which is why you are getting the error mentioned. There is nothing wrong with the code per se. You would need to investigate a dedicated public API or look at IP rotation.

Comment: Hi QHarr, How I will get Minimum price value just like Maximum price value?-Thank you

Comment: Thank you Expert, your code is working very clearly. Please let me tell how i will get minimum price value in another column?

Comment: column D already has min price. I altered the function. Let me know if this is as expected.

Comment: Yes, your code works perfectly. I also got the Minimum price.

Comment: Hello HQarro,
Actually , Yesterday I had run this code.It was working  perfecly.But now, It showing the data in column "C" are not highest price values but it showing some other data in that column.
Actually, when I debugging the line of code,     "ws.Cells(n + 1, 3).Value = arr(1) " .  It shows correct  highest price value of the Symbol.But after run , It showing some other data in column "C".

Comment: And second thing is that as I am new to coding , So I can't understand the concept of #N/A.
Still I am unable to find , Why It showing other data in column "C" and #N/A in rest of column.
I have sent my excelsheet via a link to you.Please check on this. https://pastebin.com/85NFPHF2

Comment: The #N/A is for where no value was retrieved. You could leave as blanks but I deliberately returned N/A to show that the code had been unable to access the required items most likely because .responseText was not the expected response json.

Comment: As for the highest price change - I will need to investigate this evening what the issue is you are experiencing.

Comment: OK .Ya I need your help on this.